# Allow overriding buildConfigField for local debugging, but prevent commit

Tags: android, git, gradle

My Android app communicates with a server defined in a `buildConfigField` in `app/build.gradle`:

```
buildConfigField "android.net.Uri", "server", 'android.net.Uri.parse("https://app.example.com")'
```

(We use a `buildConfigField` because this allows different "flavors" of the app to point to different servers.)

Sometimes developers need to change this value to point to a local copy of the server software running on a different server.

The problem I have is that these developers regularly forget they have made these changes and then blindly commit all of their changes to the git repository, thus breaking the app for everyone else until someone else changes it back to the original value.

Is there a way to allow developers to override the `buildConfigField` from a separate (`.gitingore`d) file so they cannot commit their changes?

Comment: @TTT Actually, your comment was helpful, because it made me realize that I can do it with `.env` and a [Gradle plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=dotenv). I'll post my own answer once I have a chance to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by a comment from @TTT, here is how I am now generating `BuildConfig` fields from a `.env` file (or Environment Variables). To prevent sharing unwanted variables (such as other system variables that might have sensitive data), it only handles variables with names that begin with `ANDROID_`.

This requires the [`co.uzzu.dotenv.gradle`](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/co.uzzu.dotenv.gradle) Gradle plugin to be set up in the project.

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().all(), { variant ->
        env.allVariables.each {
            if (it.key.startsWith("ANDROID_")) {
                def key = it.key.substring(8)
                    .split("_")
                    .collect {
                        it.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT) +
                        it.substring(1).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
                    }
                    .join("")
                key = key.substring(0,1).toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)+key.substring(1)

                def type = "String"
                def wrapper = '"%s"'
                def value = it.value
                if (value.isEmpty()) {
                    wrapper = '%s'
                    value = null
                } else if (value.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                    type = "int"
                    wrapper = '%s'
                } else if (value.matches("-?\\d+(.\\d+)")) {
                    type = "double"
                    wrapper = '%s'
                } else if (value.matches("https?://.*")) {
                    type = "android.net.Uri"
                    wrapper = 'android.net.Uri.parse("%s")'
                }
                variant.buildConfigFields.put(key, new BuildConfigField(type, String.format(wrapper, value), "Field from .env"))
            }
        }
    })
}
```

It supports variables that are `boolean`, `int`, `double`, `String`, or `android.net.Uri` (though only `String` can be `null` since it cannot determine the type without a value).